# Как пройти PageSpeed Tools?

Tags: javascript, html, jquery, css

Кто мне может подсказать как улучшить показатели `PageSpeed`. Проект маленький, по сути лендинг. Использую сборку `gulp`. Изображения все оптимизированы на максимум, онлайн оптимизаторы не сжимают больше. Подключаю несколько скриптов через `cdn`. Пока их нет, результат хороший, как только добавляю, показатели падают на 73-76 %. Хочу добиться хотя бы зеленной зоны. При подключении локально плагинов, результат тот же. Кто-то может подсказать как решить эту проблему?

Даже если `slick` убираю, все равно 76%. Только jquey & bootstrap так понижает показатели

// Подключаю в `head`

```
<link rel="icon" type="image/png" href="./public/images/favicon.png" />
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://stackpath.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.1.3/css/bootstrap.min.css" integrity="sha384-MCw98/SFnGE8fJT3GXwEOngsV7Zt27NXFoaoApmYm81iuXoPkFOJwJ8ERdknLPMO" crossorigin="anonymous">
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/slick-carousel/1.9.0/slick.min.css" />
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/slick-carousel/1.9.0/slick-theme.min.css" />
<link rel="stylesheet" href="./public/css/main.css">
```

// Подключаю внизу страницы, перед `</body>`

```
<script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-3.3.1.slim.min.js"></script>    
<script defer src="https://stackpath.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.1.3/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>
<script defer src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/slick-carousel/1.9.0/slick.min.js"></script>
<script defer src="./public/js/matchHeight.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
<script defer src="./public/js/script.js"></script>
```

Comment: Сейчас меня забросают камнями, но как насчет сделать этот маленький проект без подключения килограммов скриптов?

Comment: Я могу отказаться от нескольких, но не от всех. В зеленой зоне только если отказаться от всего кроме `jquery`

Comment: Собери все плагины локально, в 1 файл и минимизируй его. Слайдер, бутстрап, жуквери, прям всё в одну кучу сгреби. Показатели будут еще выше, если всю эту сжатую кучу подключать не через файл, а вставить прямиком в тег `script`

Comment: Не могу представить, как на лендинге можно использовать все компонеты `bootstrap`, если используете gulp используйте `sass` версию `bootstrap` и отключите то, что не используете и как написал @dev_null соберите все в один файл `css` и `js`.

Comment: Спасибо! Именно объединение в один файл улучшает скорость загрузки страницы. Именно в этом, моем случае

Answer (score 3):

Я бы посоветовал вам оптимизировать весь статический контент на сайте.

#### Сжатие графики

В вашем случае кроме сжатия стилей и скриптов посоветую сжимать и графику. К примеру, картинки можно легко сжать без потери качества только за счет удаление exif-данных. На реальном сайте можно сократить размер картинок в среднем на 70%, что на современном сайте равняется примерно 4 МБ. Пример на `gulp`:

```
var
    gulp = require('gulp'),
    imagemin = require('gulp-imagemin'),
    imageminJR = require('imagemin-jpeg-recompress'),
    imageminSvgo = require('imagemin-svgo');

// Optimizing images
gulp.task('imagemin', function() {
    gulp.src('./img/**/*')
        .pipe(imagemin([
            imageminJR({
                method: 'ms-ssim'
            }),
            imageminSvgo({
                plugins: [
                    {removeViewBox: false}
                ]
            })
        ]))
        .pipe(gulp.dest('./public/img/'))
});
```

А для браузеров, которые понимают легковесный формат `webp` (формат разработан Google), можно сделать еще такой вариант изображений:

```
var
    gulp = require('gulp'),
    webp = require('gulp-webp');

// Generate Webp
gulp.task('webp', function() {
    gulp.src('./img/**/*')
        .pipe(webp())
        .pipe(gulp.dest('./public/img/'))
});
```

#### Оптимизация скриптов

Сперва объедините все скрипты в один файл и минифицируйте их. Это помет сократить количество HTTP-запросов и размер файлов:

```
var
    gulp = require('gulp'),
    concat = require('gulp-concat'),
    uglify = require('gulp-uglify');

// Concat JS
gulp.task('js', function(){
    gulp.src([
        './js/jquery.js',
        './js/wow.js',
        './js/menu.js',
        './js/scrollspy.js',
        './js/main.js',
        './js/temp/contact.bundled.js',
        './js/owl.carousel.js'
    ])
        .pipe(concat('script.js'))
        .pipe(uglify())
        .pipe(gulp.dest('./public/js/'))
});
```

#### Оптимизация стилей

Кроме обычной минификации стилей можно использовать и продвинутую - объединять дубликаты классов и @media. Пример на `gulp` из моего [web-starter-kit][1]:

```
var
    gulp = require('gulp'),
    stylus = require('gulp-stylus'),

    // Минифицирует CSS, объединяет классы. Не ломает CSS, в отличие от cssnano, который, к примеру, может неправильно выставлять z-index
    csso = require('gulp-csso'),

    // Объединяет все @media
    cmq = require('gulp-combine-mq'),

    // Сокращает CSS-селекторы    
    gs = require('gulp-selectors'),

    // Проставляет вендорные префиксы
    autoprefixer = require('gulp-autoprefixer'),

    livereload = require('gulp-livereload'),
    nib = require('nib');

// Compiling Stylus in CSS
gulp.task('css', function() {
    gulp.src('./styl/*.styl')
        .pipe(stylus({
            use: nib()
        }))
        .pipe(cmq())
        .pipe(csso())
        .pipe(autoprefixer('last 3 versions'))
        .pipe(gulp.dest('./public/css/'))
});
```

А если совсем делать нечего, то можно еще и селекторы сократить:

```
// Minify selectors
    gulp.task('gs', function() {
        var ignores = {
            classes: ['active', 'menu', 'nav', 'slide', 'error', 'form-control', 'loader', 'showLoader', 'fadeLoader', 'webp', 'wow', 'owl-*', 'i-*'],
            ids: '*'
        };
        gulp.src(['./public/**/*.css', './public/**/*.html'])
            .pipe(gs.run({}, ignores))
            .pipe(gulp.dest('./public/'))
    });
```

Кстати, наверняка у вас есть классы, добавляющиеся через JS, поэтому предварительно стоит все такие классы вынести в переменную `ignores`.

#### Кеширование статики на стороне пользователя

Также бы посоветовал кешировать скрипты и стили на стороне пользователя, чтобы исключить их повторную загрузку, если они не изменились:

```
<FilesMatch ".(flv|gif|jpg|jpeg|png|ico|svg|swf|js|css|pdf|woff2|woff|ttf|eot)$">
  Header set Cache-Control "max-age=2592000"
</FilesMatch>
```

#### Сжатие передаваемых данных и переход на HTTP/2

Немалое преимущество в оптимизации даёт сжатие передаваемых данных. На данный момент есть два метода сжатия: **gzip** и **brotli**.

Для Apache включить **gzip** можно пропивав в `.htaccess`:

```
# сжатие text, html, javascript, css, xml:
<ifModule mod_deflate.c>
AddOutputFilterByType DEFLATE text/html text/plain text/xml application/xml application/xhtml+xml text/css text/javascript application/javascript application/x-javascript
</ifModule>
```

Алгоритм **brotli** будет немного эффективней, чем **gzip**, но его можно использовать лишь с `HTTP/2`, а для работы `HTTP/2` нужен SSL-сертификат. Если у вас на сайте уже есть сертификат, то немедленно переходите на `HTTP/2`. Кроме поддержки **brotli** сам протокол даст возможность выполнять множество запросов в рамках одного соединения – статические элементы загрузятся параллельно и не будут блокировать друг друга, как это происходит в `HTTP/1.1`.

Comment: как включается gzip сжатие?

Comment: @Kyper на серверной стороне. В зависимости от того, какой веб-сервер у вас используется. Если у вас Apache отвечает за отдачу, то скопируйте строку из ответа в .htaccess

Comment: сейчас интерфейс у инструмента изменился. Вместе с тем и снизился балл ранее оптимизированных сайтов. Ваши рекомендации остались актуальными?

Comment: @Kyper рекомендации актуальные, но я бы добавил ещё поддержку http 2.0 и сжатие brotly. Ещё можно реализовать Critical Path CSS. И было бы неплохо отказаться от внешних библиотек.

Comment: @Kyper не воспринимайте как рекламу, но здесь делали https://developers.google.com/speed/pagespeed/insights/?hl=ru&url=https%3A%2F%2F1000.tech%2Fen